# Reading pixel values of a bmp file using Python 3.x on Mac os terminal

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, binary, bmp

I'm trying to read in `width`, `height` and `color depth` of a `bmp` file and output the values as `Integers`. Im using the `.seek` method to skip the unneeded bytes and the `.read` method to read in the bytes containing the needed Information `(offsets 18, 22 and 28)`.

```
def bytes2int(b):
    res = 0
    for x in b[::-1]:
        res = (res << 8) + x
    return res
f = open("red.bmp", "rb")
f.seek(18)
print("Width: ", bytes2int(f.read(4)), "px")
print("Height: ", bytes2int(f.read(4)), "px")
f.seek(2, 1)
print("Colordepth: ", bytes2int(f.read(2)), "bmp")
f.close()
```

So when I try to run the code using mac os terminal I receive a TypeError...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "Untitled.py", line 12, in <module>
    print("Width: ", bytes2int(f.read(4)), "px")

File "Untitled.py", line 8, in bytes2int
    res = (res << 8) + x

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I'm trying to understand the problem for weeks now and would be very happy if someone finds time to help me out.

Here's a [bmp test file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/654w0vwt9y68sho/red.bmp?dl=0):

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using Python 3.6.3 on my Windows machine—which doesn't surprise me because your code looks OK. The different OS doesn't explain your `TypeError` however since it should have occurred regardless.

Comment: What shows if you add a `print(type(f.read(4)))` right after opening the file? I get `<class 'bytes'>` on my system. In the function, what does `print(type(x))` display inside the `for` loop? I get `<class 'int'>`.

Comment: Ok thats weird I get a `<type ´str´>` output on both plus the above stated TypeError of course...

Comment: Sure you're running Python 3.x? Try printing the value of `sys.version` and see what it says (`import sys` first, of course).

Comment: Yes I'm currently on 3.6.1

`import os, sys
print(sys.version)
3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]`

Comment: In that case, the problem definitely doesn't make sense. Meanwhile you can workaround it with something like `res = (res << 8) + ord(x)`.

Comment: That worked thank you very much :)